# PHP Undefined index using ternary operator

Tags: php, ternary-operator

my PHP version is 5.3.5.

**The code:**

```
$num = $_REQUEST['num'] ?: 7;
```

**The error:**

```
Notice: Undefined index: num in C:\path\to\file.php on line 34
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Oh, and by the way everything works I just get the ugly error too.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
$num = isset($_REQUEST['num']) ? $_REQUEST['num'] : 7;
```

I assume you want `$_REQUEST['num']` if it's set otherwise 7.

Comment: Me by another 30 seconds.  But I at least cast the incoming int.  : )

Also... I'll never use isset again.  It never does exactly what you want it to do.  array_key_exists() and empty() are your friends.

Comment: Yes, use array_key_exists() instead.

Answer (score 6):

This is expected behavior; according to http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=45760, the `?:` shortcut is just that:  a shortcut.

In other words:

```
$num = $_REQUEST['num'] ?: 7;
```

is evaluated identically to:

```
$num = $_REQUEST['num'] ? $_REQUEST['num'] : 7;
```

and everything that implies (and is addressed quite adequately by the other answers in the thread).

Comment: Apparently Sims and I think alike.  I like the shortcut -- so I'll give you a +1, even though you didn't answer the op's question and not casting the $_REQUEST is also problematic.  : )

Answer (score 6):

Isn't using error suppression for short assignment code good ?.

we can write $price = @$rec['Product']['new'] ?: $rec['Product']['old'];

Using @ saved me from repeating of same variable and allowed me to use short cut ternary operator without generating notice.

I know using @ is considered not good but for this particular case, I don't imagine anything could go wrong ever.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If it isn't in the request, you may get a warning.

You're better off doing this:

```
$num = (array_key_exists('num', $_REQUEST)) ? intval($_REQUEST['num']) : 7;
```

Comment: `array_key_exists` is kind of pointless in this context though. The $_REQUEST superglobals can only ever contain strings, not NULL values. While `isset` used for error suppressing is also questionable, it's sufficient to check for the presence of entries here.

Comment: It is just on my verboten keyword list.  I specifically don't use isset for anything because I think it is generally just too fraught with errors.

Comment: @mario, What is your point about strings and NULL values? If there is a key called 'num' array_key_exists will return true.

Comment: @sims - not to speak for him, but one of the major known/accepted problems with isset() is that if you call isset() on a variable which contains null, it returns true.  Which is one of those 'not what I wanted' error cases that I was referring to.

Comment: @John Green - PageSpike, which is why I think your suggestion of array_key_exists is the way to go. I don't see how array_key_exists is pointless in this context. Though, I am probably overlooking something, which is why I asked.

Comment: @sims - got it.  In this case, we're talking about the $_REQUEST superglobal -- which can never have a null key.

Comment: @John Green - PageSpike, Aha. The lights flicker on! So in this case it is alright to use isset. I would still avoid it though. But that's me being paranoid.

Comment: @sims - I'm definitely in your camp.  : )

Answer (score 2):

I second dhaval solution of using @ error suppression, what is more readable:

$num = @$_REQUEST['num'] ?: 7;

..or..

$num = (array_key_exists('num', $_REQUEST)) ? $_REQUEST['num'] : 7;

I know which I would prefer to read if I was trying to understand someone else's code. I think it provides the happy medium between setting error_reporting to E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE (very bad) and the boilerplate code above.

Answer (score 1):

`$num = (isset($_REQUEST['num'])) ? $_REQUEST['num'] : 7;`

Answer (score 1):

Accessing an array with an index that doesn't exist is always going to throw a notice. You need to either ignore the notice since that does return null, or technically you're supposed to use `array_key_exists`.

Answer (score 0):

another approach:

```
$num = $_REQUEST['num'] ?? "" ?: 7;
```

Comment: Need more details about what your answers is actually doing, please comment.